# Best way to implement same command with different parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

I have a `Template` for my `ListViewItems` where I add a `Button`.

The `Button` should trigger some kind of delete `Command`. But every `ListViewItem` is unique so the `Button` should take a `Parameter` to identify which `Button` or`ListViewItem` was clicked.

Now my question is, what is the best way to implement that?

I'm fairly new to `WPF` but I try to follow the `MVVM` as much as possible. I tried to look up some tutorials for custom `Commands` etc. but somehow I understand it and I don't want to use a third party tool, since I only have three `Buttons` on my `Window` which do something.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the the ideas with the index. But I would really appreciate it if somebody had a link to a tutorial which explains how to set up a simple command.
I'm not talking about the XML more about the C# behind where the whole command part is created.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                                    
                <Border BorderBrush="#5076A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#C0D3EA" Offset="1.0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <StackPanel TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextElement.FontSize="12">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Betreff}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Button FontSize="7" Content="X" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Kunde}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Ort}"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Alternative}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: pass listview item index as parameter to command

Comment: @RajeevRanjan depending on your `CollectionView`, the index in the `ListBox` may not align with the index in the source collection. Item index should be considered a view implementation detail. Instead, operate on object references of domain specific data model IDs.

Comment: post some code, but the answer from Rui should work for you

Comment: why you create the command stuff in code behind? can you post this pls too

Comment: That is the Problem, I don't have any sort of command yet. I need to create the class etc.

Comment: did you check DelegateCommand or RelayCommand?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the ItemsSource is bound to a list of Item where Item has a property named Id

```
<Window.Resources>
 <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <Button Command={Binding DoSomethingCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}} CommandParameter={Binding Id}>Do something</Command>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If you omit the source of the binding in the data template, the source will be the item itself. You can then use any property of item as a parameter to your command, in this example, that will be Id.